# Docker - Container is not created after create service

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I want to create a service from rabbitmq image so I try to run the following command:

```
docker service create --name rabbitmq --hostname rabbitmq --publish 5672:5672 --publish 15672:15672 --mount source=rabbitmq,target=/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.10-management
```

Then I run the command `docker service ls` to see if the service is created and everything looks ok, but when I run `docker ps` the container is not created.

The weird thing is that `docker service ls` looks like this:

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                        PORTS
ye8r8xk2k49c        rabbitmq            replicated          1/1                 rabbitmq:3.6.10-management   *:5672->5672/tcp,*:15672->15672/tcp
```

Can someone help me with this issue?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you type 'docker ps -a' the container appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
docker service ps rabbitmq
```

This will tell you which node is running the container for your service.

`docker ps` will only show the container for the current node and not your swarm cluster